# cygwin cannot find make program

Tags: java, android, makefile, android-ndk, cygwin

What I'm trying to do is successfully compile native code using Cygwin. The error message i get when i run type my directory to the ndk-build in the terminal is

ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

This is what im typing into the Cygwin terminal:

C:/users/kwesi/desktop/android-ndk-r8/ndk-build

My Build Path is:
C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Users\Kwesi\Desktop\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build;

I've installed the make using this youtube video tutorial, so I am pretty sure it is installed correctly.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqJGxJJq87w&list=FL2bdE2OcpySONpqzf5OsWNQ&index=1&feature=plpp_video

Comment: Have you installed make using Cygwin's setup.exe? You must select it from the list of the packages (select "Bin" in the corresponding column).

Comment: I had selected "bin" and "src" in all "make" related package columns. It resolved the error of not finding a 'make' program, but now I'm stuck with exception handling issues in my make file :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably just need to install the `make` package.

Run the `setup.exe` command that you used to install Cygwin in the first place, and select "make".

First, to confirm that this is the problem, run `make` from the terminal.

You'll likely have to install some other packages as well.

Comment: @TheObliviator: Did you try installing `make` via Cygwin's `setup.exe`, as gfour and I both suggested?

Comment: Apparently I did not solve the problem.  I followed a youtube tutorial on installing the make so i am pretty sure the make is installed correctly, but I am still getting that error.  I dont know what else i should try.

Comment: @TheObliviator: You said that you tried installing `make` using Cygwin's `setup.exe`, and it didn't work (though you didn't tell us *how* it didn't work). Now you've accepted my answer suggesting that you install `make` via Cygwin's `setup.exe`. So what happened?

Comment: I have same issue, the make package shows in the cywyn setup as installed but I keep getting the message

Comment: @ThePoet: Since the OP never explained how my answer solved his problem, maybe you can help. Try these commands: `ls -l /usr/bin/make.exe`, `type -a make`, `/usr/bin/make --version`, `make --version`

Comment: I'll do right now, just be a little patient while I figure out how to run those commands

Comment: @TheTokenizer: On 2012-06-06, you posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10908148/827263) (which I didn't see until now) saying that you had solved the problem by following a YouTube video. Two days later, you posted a comment above saying that you were still getting the same error after following the video. Later that month, you accepted my answer, even though you had said that what I suggested did not work (though you never mentioned (*now* it failed to work). And now somebody else appears to be having a similar problem. Can you please clarify what happened?

Comment: ok, it seems to be working now. After trying to install/uninstall several times I just tried to not change the default folder cygwin was installed and it is working fine(which means my project compiling). I hope it helps somebody

Comment: Almost forgot, and of course I updated the environment variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45680/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-the-poet)

Comment: @ThePoet: Without knowing which environment variable you updated, this is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using windows? I am using windows 7, had the same problem using cygwin. I had MinGW installed and using cygwin, it was looking for a cygwin-compatible make program. Downloaded and set up a path for GNUMAKE but the problem still persist. So I tried using the MinGW, opened up msys.bat and voila, it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with adding cygwin\bin path to System Environment Variables.